# Mostrar error 403 en ventana modal

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap

En mi proyecto realizado con laravel estoy implementando roles y permisos a usuarios del sistema. Tengo el inconveniente que no puedo mostrar el error 403 en mi ventana modal. Es decir si el usuario logueado por ejemplo no tiene permiso de crear una orden necesito mostrar la siguiente vista con el error indicado:

vista 403

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

    <section class="pages container">
        <div class="page page-about">
            <h1 class="text-capitalize">Página no autorizada</h1>           
            <p>Regresar a <a href="{{ route('pages.home') }}">Inicio</a></p>
        </div>
    </section>

@endsection
```

**Necesito mostrarla en una ventana modal.** Ahora el tema es así ya tengo una ventana modal que utilizo para crear una orden  y editar una orden.
Si el usuario no tiene el permiso tanto como para crear o editar  una orden. Me gustaría informarlo utilizando la misma ventana modal, entonces como capturo el error con jquery para reutilizar la misma ventana y notificarlo?.

O en todo caso como lo deberia hacer?

Así es como se ve actualmente si el usuario no tiene el permiso necesario (crear orden)

[image: 403]

modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header"> 

                <a href="{{ route('admin.customers.create') }}" class="btn btn-success pull-right modal-show" style="margin-top: -8px;" title="Crear Cliente"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Crear cliente</a>           
                <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> -->
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Form Input</h4>               
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">          
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"  id="modal-btn-delete" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  id="modal-btn-save">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-show', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href'),
        title = me.attr('title');     

    $('#modal-title').text(title);
    $('#modal-btn-delete').text(me.hasClass('btn btn-warning') ? '' : 'Cerrar');     
    $('#modal-btn-save').removeClass('hide')
    .text(me.hasClass('edit') ? 'Actualizar' : 'Crear');     

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modal-body').html(response);  

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                language: 'es'
            });             

            $('#name_company').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selecciona empresa',
                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',']
            });

            $('#name_product').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selecciona producto',
                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',']
            });

            $('#name').select2({
                placeholder: 'Selecciona operario',
                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',']
            });

            var name_companySelect = $('#name_company');
            var phone_company = $('#phone_company');
            var name_client = $('#name_client');
            var phone_client = $('#phone_client');
            var email = $('#email');            
            var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');    
            // console.log (name_companySelect);
            name_companySelect.on('change', function() {
                // console.log ('la compañía ha cambiado');
                var id = $(this).val();
                // console.log('id del Company seleccionado: ' + id);
                obtenerDetalleDeCompany(id)

            });            

            function obtenerDetalleDeCompany(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    // url: 'companies/' + id,
                    url: '/admin/orders/' + id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {            
                        '_token': csrf_token
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // acá podés loguear la respuesta del servidor
                        console.log(response);
                        // le pasás la data a la función que llena los otros inputs
                        llenarInputs(response);
                    },
                    error: function () { 
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('Hubo un error obteniendo el detalle de la Compañía!');
                    }
                })
            }

            function llenarInputs(data) {
                // $clientes->company['phone_company']
                phone_company.val(data.company.phone_company);  
                name_client.val(data.name_client);    
                phone_client.val(data.phone_client);    
                email.val(data.email);    
            }           
        }
    }); 

    $('#modal').modal('show');      
});
```